# How can I make my website appear in the top position of Google?

Tags: seo

I have added some of the keywords in a meta tag, but my site is still not in the top position when Googled. How can I achieve this?

Comment: The keywords meta tag are a myth.

Answer (score 1):

There is no definitive answer and all answers will be completely opinion based.

Keyword meta tags are **NOT** used in search engine ranking. If you would like a more definitive answer see the following post [here](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.co.uk/2009/09/google-does-not-use-keywords-meta-tag.html).

The best thing you can do is:

1.) Keep adding fresh content, comments and blog posts and create RSS feeds for Google and submit these as sitemaps to Google.

2.) Keep all content unique and don't duplicate content. Google is currently fighting to keep all content on there search engine unique and non-duplicated. So make sure you add canonical links to your page. See [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139394?hl=en) to learn how to do so.

3.) Make sure your website is responsive. Google also wants sites to display fast and correctly on all devices and you may be penalised if your website is too slow on mobile device.

4.) H1 tags, Meta descriptions, titles, and Meta Tags. This said, with meta tags not being relevant, it won't hurt to make them relevant to your content. However have one and only one H1 tag, and make sure it is relevant to your content. Same goes for your meta description and title tags.

5.) Website speed is an important factor. Google recommends that all websites should load in less then 2 seconds. In this case make sure all images are optimised, don't load unnecessary resources, set a cache in your *.htaccess*, enable persistent TCP connections, add gzip to your resources, and combine all off your `CSS` files into one and minify them, same with you `JS` files.

All my suggestions are of my own opinion and they are all onsite optimisation. You will be required to gather relevant backlinks but make sure you don't participate in a linking scheme. Please also note that bad links and spam content can potentially harm your website causing much bigger issues.

Social Media can also be a good source of traffic and can be used as a very powerful SEO tool if used properly.

The main point would be: Don't expect results overnight, this process will take a very long time and it may take a lot of work and time before you start seeing results. Make sure you target the right keywords for your site doing research on your target keywords, analyse your competition, what are they doing that you aren't doing, how many backlinks do they have. None of this however will guarantee you a top spot. If it was that easy then everyone would be doing it.

The best place to start is by looking [here](http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/www.google.co.uk/en/uk/webmasters/docs/search-engine-optimization-starter-guide.pdf), as this is written by Google and will advise you on the best practices.

Comment: +1 Nicely detailed. I'd suggest adding this to the marked duplicate question as a Community Wiki answer.

Comment: @dan how would i do that? Thanks for the +1

Comment: Click on _edit_ and copy the answer completely, then click on the marked duplicate question and paste it into an Answer box at the bottom of the page. It should already be marked as a Community Wiki answer because the question is. Nice answers - it would be great to see more detailed answers like these on this site.

Comment: @dan cheers, have done as you have said.

Answer (score 0):

There is not "a way to do it"... you can achieve it or not. Why should be you and not others, when they are doing the same than you, and possibly better, or just have more luck regarding the unpredictable Google algorithms?

Answer (score 0):

Getting found right exactly at the top of major search engines (like Google) requires you to have a strategic approach to it. On-Site optimization might not be enough to attain maximum visibility. That is why there are Off-Site optimization strategies like link building, content marketing and social media marketing to push your website at the top of the results page.